# Why is encoding different when run on Windows 8 and Windows Server 2012

Tags: c#, unicode, encoding, utf-8, multipartform-data

I have a wcf service which basically allows people to post information to my Microsoft sql database using a moble app.  I'm getting very frustrated when trying to post French content. i.e. "Poignée",  I'm making use of a mulitpart/form-data parser ( https://github.com/Vodurden/Http-Multipart-Data-Parser/tree/master/HttpMultipartParser, however the moment the parser tries to process a character dec > 128 ( i.e  character é in the word: Poignée in ( BinaryReader.Read()  line 283 of BinaryStreamStacks.cs ... shown below ) it blows up. with an error: ("The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback 'System.Text.DecoderReplacementFallback'.\r\nParameter name: chars")

```
 public byte[] ReadByteLine(out bool hitStreamEnd)
    {
        hitStreamEnd = false;
        if (!this.HasData())
        {
            // No streams, no data!
            return null;
        }

        // This is horribly inefficient, consider profiling here if
        // it becomes an issue.
        BinaryReader top = this.streams.Peek();
        byte[] ignore = this.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(new[] { '\r' });
        byte[] search = this.CurrentEncoding.GetBytes(new[] { '\n' });
        int searchPos = 0;
        var builder = new MemoryStream();

        while (true)
        {
            // First we need to read a byte from one of the streams
            int b = top.Read();  //  error occurs here...
```

.....

If I set the encoding within the multipart/parser on the wcf end to use Encoding.GetEncoding(1252));then I manage to make things work out and the string "Poignée" gets processed correctly, however when I try to save it to the sql database I first need to convert the string out to unicode before writing it to my database.  Anyway every works using this approach on my development machine,  ( Windows 8 ),  the problem is that when I publish my wcf service to my Server 2013 machine Is starts to save Poignée as  PoignÃ©e.  why is it working differently on my windows server 2013 machine then it does on my Windows 8 machine and what can I do to fix it..

P.S. in case you haven't; figured it out I'm finding saving French characters very frustrating..

Thanks,

Comment: Hard to unravel, the BinaryReader initialization looks bizarre.  And talking about "byte" in the code when you use a method that returns Char sure is a red flag.  But it sounds to me like the problem is located on the other end of the wire.  Seems that this mobile app sends text in an arbitrary encoding.  Giving you no shot at all at figuring out what the correct encoding needs to be.  If you don't like the French now then wait until East Asia comes online :)

Comment: Hi,

@HansPassant the mobile app on the other end is written by me so I have full control over it.  I'm converting my string utf-8 from within it.. i.e.

`QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart
(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
QHttpPart textPart;
textPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"psPostAdContactBBM\""));
textPart.setBody(psPostAdContactBBM.toUtf8());
multiPart->append(textPart);`